# Как обновлять проекты в FirstCode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, codefirst

При добавлении новых классов-таблиц в DbContext выдает ошибку и приходиться удалять базу и заново запускать проект

Comment: Используйте [механизм миграций](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте механизм миграций.
Чтобы включить миграции, нужно выполнить команду `Enable-Migrations` в консоли диспетчера `NuGet` (открыть консоль в Visual Studio можно с помощью команды меню `Tools --> Library Package Manager --> Package manager Console`).
Выполните в той же консоле команду:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName "CodeFirst" -StartUpProjectName "ProfessorWeb.EntityFramework"
```

> Указание директив ProjectName и StartUpProjectName не обязательно.
>   Напомню, что в нашем тестовом проекте модель данных определяется в
>   проекте классов CodeFirst, а само приложение ASP.NET, где мы работаем
>   с данными, называется ProfessorWeb.EntityFramework, поэтому в этой
>   команде я явно задал имена проектов. Если вы используете модель
>   Code-First в том же проекте, где работаете с данными, указывать эти
>   директивы необязательно, достаточно просто выполнить команду
>   Enable-Migrations.

После запуска этой команды, в проекте CodeFirst будет добавлена новая папка Migrations, содержащая два файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если все изменения в них вас устраивают, вы можете обновить базу данных на основе данной миграции, использовав команду `Update-Database`:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName "CodeFirst"
```

Почитать подробнее можно [здесь](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_11.php) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)